# In powerBi how can i separate a column with text, positive and negative decimal numbers to different columns please

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

I have a the below column in PowerBI where Value column has decimal numbers both positive and negative and text. I need all of these to be in different columns.

How can I do that please.

| Values |
| --- |
| -20.1 |
| 10 |
| 31.2 |
| on |
| off |
| disarmed |
| armed |
| 33 |
| -20 |

Comment: all values (from all row) are in same format? how many values are there in your sample data? show them differently so the required output becomes undestandable to the reader.

Comment: If that example is a standard format, use Column from examples, to create a new column for each item
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-add-column-from-example

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```vb
let
    Source = Table.FromList({"-20.1","10","31.2","on","off","disarmed","armed","33","-20"}, null, {"Values"}),
    add_Negative = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Negative", each try  if Number.From([Values])<0 then Number.From([Values]) else null otherwise null, type number),
    add_Positive = Table.AddColumn(add_Negative, "Positive", each try  if Number.From([Values])>0 then Number.From([Values]) else null otherwise null, type number),
    add_Text = Table.AddColumn(add_Positive, "Text", each if Text.Remove(Text.From([Values]),{"0".."9","-","."}) = "" then null else [Values], type text)
in
    add_Text
```

Comment: did that work for you?